# manipulate bytes down to binary levels in python

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, binary

I am trying to start learning about writing encryption algorithms, so while using python I am trying to manipulate data down to a binary level so I can add bits to the end of data as well as manipulate to obscure the data.

I am not new to programming I am actually a programmer but I am relatively new to python which is why I am struggling a bit.

can anyone show me the best way to manipulate, in python, a string down to the binary level (or recommend in what way I should approach this). I have looked at a number of questions:

[Convert string to binary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python)

[Manipulating binary data in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059301/manipulating-binary-data-in-python)

[Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa-python)

But all these are not what I am looking for and I do not know enough of python to be able to pick out what I need. can someone please assist me with details (if you use a function please explain what it is to me e.g. ord())

Comment: what python version are you using? Strings are an abstraction. Make sure you understand what encoding is and how it works. See [this tutorial](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) and [this one](http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html)

Comment: i am using 3.5 and yes I understand how encoding works, dont worry about that. I am a primarily  a PHP and MySQL developer encoding is the bane of my existence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [bitstring](http://scott-griffiths.github.io/bitstring/) module, which is designed to make binary manipulation as easy as possible.

```
from bitstring import BitArray
a = BitArray('0xfeed')    # 16 bits from hex
a += '0b001'              # Add three binary bits
a.replace('0b111', '0b0') # Search and replace
a.count(1)                # Count one bits
```

It has a full [manual](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/) and lots of examples.

Comment: I got the results returned as 3 and 5 (5 on the count) why is this? 3 i am guessing is the x=n instances replaced?

Comment: Yes the 3 is the number of replacements done. Try `a.bin` to look at the binary representation at any time.

Answer (score 2):

[bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.8.1) lets you treat bit sequences as normal Python sequences and to operate on them as binary values.

```
>>> bitarray.bitarray('0101') | bitarray.bitarray('1010')
bitarray('1111')
```